# AMD RX 580 is stuck at max memory clock frequency

Tags: xubuntu, display, amd-graphics, radeon, 22.04

According to `radeontop`, the memory clock of my videocard is stuck at 100% (2GHz).

The videocard is `Sapphire AMD Radeon RX 580`. I'm running a 1920x1080 monitor at 144hz. The problem doesn't happen at 60hz. I'm running the opensource `amdgpu` driver, which Ubuntu installs by default. I'm using Xorg, not Wayland.

This didn't happen in Ubuntu 20.04, first started happening in 21.10, and still happens in a fresh install of 22.04 (kernel is `5.15.0-25-generic`).

[This reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/dgyblg/rx_5700xt_memory_clock_stuck_at_max_clock_even/) says this is done intentionally as a workaround for visual glitches/flickering. I did get the glitches in 20.04, but those were rare, and I'd prefer to have them rather than to be stuck with max memory clock.

---

Following `xrandr` command seems to solve the issue, but I'm not sure how to properly run it automatically.

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080x143.98"  346.500000  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1087 1157  +HSync -VSync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-A-1 1920x1080x143.98
xrandr --output HDMI-A-1 --mode 1920x1080x143.98
```

This modeline was calculated using [UMC](https://sourceforge.net/projects/umc/files/), by running `umc 1920 1080 144 -rbt`.

I can run it at login, but then it gets reset every time the display mode changes, such as when logging out or (I believe) when locking the screen.

I can run it every 10 seconds, but then I can't use any fullscreen application that wants a different mode.

Surely there must be a better way of applying custom modelines.

Comment: Better apply your modes in [xorg.conf](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/xorg.conf.5.html)

Comment: @pasmanpasmański Do you know what exactly I need to write there? I tried several things, but it seems my custom modeline was ignored, and wasn't even mentioned in xorg logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have a radeon for testing, but you may try this `xorg.conf` file:

```
  Section "Device"
    Identifier      "Radeon"
    Option          "monitor-HDMI-A-1" "Samsung"
  EndSection
  
  Section "Monitor"
    Identifier      "Samsung"
    Modeline "1920x1080_143"  346.50  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1087 1157  +HSync -VSync
  EndSection
 
  Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "Default Screen"
    Monitor         "Samsung"
    Device          "Radeon"
  EndSection
```

Comment: Seems to work so far, much thanks!